# How to maintain order of a Mongo collection by sorting on an indexed field efficiently

Tags: mongodb, sorting

```
ObjectId _id  <--- index
String UserName
int Points <--- Descending index
```

Using this document structure as a simple example, we have a collection of users, each with a name and a "points" value. The collection has the usual `_id` index but also a "descending index" on `Points`.

### Problem

The sample use case would be to maintain a ranking scoreboard (something like the League of Legends/DOTA ranking system or chess elo system). Each users' `Points` field would be constantly changing but the scoreboard is viewed very frequently and thus needs to be accurately maintained.

### My current unoptimized solution

I'm not sure what "ascending/descending sort order means" in the [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/), but apparently it doesn't matter for single-field indices anyways.
So currently I'm just doing a very brute force solution of sorting the collection each time a user's `Points` field gets updated. At least it's indexed so for a smaller userbase this shouldn't be too bad. However, sorting the entire userbase on each update/insertion just seems wrong in general.

### Other things I'm considering

There are data structures traditionally used for maintaining order during insert/update such as search trees but implementing that without putting the entire collection in memory seems like a huge project in itself.

I tried to search for some built-in functionality of Mongo indices that automatically maintains order in the collection for you but I couldn't really find anything like that.

Maybe some logic to only re-sort only some chunk of documents directly above and below the insertion/update? This solution seems pretty dependent on the expected spread of `Points` across the userbase and the use cases of this system.

Comment: See [this post's](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing) topic on Covered Queries. This is about using indexing efficiently for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to sort additionally already created indices , when you create indices in mongoDB you specify in what direction they need to be sorted(ascending(1) or descending(-1)) , so when you search multiple documents based on some field the result will be already sorted based on this field index order.
Afcourse you can specify explicitly if you need the result in reverse order or sorted by other field.

Comment: What about batch find? For example if I find a batch of 1000 documents with an offset of 0. Would the results be sorted relative to the entire collection or just the batch of 1000 documents?

Comment: as already commented depending on criteria used to search in the targeted index , the result of 1000 documents will be sorted based on the index fields from the entire collection

Comment: If you dont use any indices the result order will be based on document _id ( natural order ) or since the _id is based on insertion date output will be ordered based on insertion date

Comment: ok thanks, i think I have what i need now. just need to look up how such an index affects insertion/update

Comment: Adding unnecessary indices slow down inserts/updates , so it is best to add only the indices you need...